# What is difference between Google fs and Red Hat GFS?

Tags: redhat, google, gfs

can same tell me what is difference between Google fs and RedHat GFS ? I have google for the same but very little info got.

Thanks for all you support!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See for yourself; there are good descriptions at wikipedia of both the [Google Filesystem](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Google_File_System) and RedHat's [Global Filesystem](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Global_File_System) ; in general, the biggest difference looks to be that GoogleFS is a file-object level FS and Redhat's GFS is block-level.  As with most comparisons, it depends a lot on what you're looking to do.

Answer (score 2):

There's more differences than commonalities in these two. The single largest difference (IMO) is that GoogleFS is distributed, something more like Ceph than GFS.